# Can I run 2 Node.js Project in windows?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dedicated-server

Can I run **2 Node.js** Project in windows?

*If yes, How Can I do That?*
*If no, Can I run 2 Node.js Project in a dedicated Host?*

Comment: You can use different ports. [Two node.js servers?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12491251)

Comment: How?, I want run 2 telegram bot in same time

Comment: [This Google Group Discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/FOkOcKQ68Ew) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of options.
If you want to have diffrent versions of nodeJS, for windows [NVM-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is the best option.

But instead if you're talking about running different http-request based programs, the simplest solution is to simply listen at different ports on each of the project on your system.
Eg, if you're using nodejs http module

```
// project 1
server.listen('8080', (err) => { // Will start up the server on port 8080
  console.log(`server is listening on 8080`)
})

// project 2
server.listen('8081', (err) => { // Will start up the server on port 8081
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`)
})
```

or if you're using express server

```
// project 1
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('app listening on port 3000 for project 1 !');
  })

// project 2
app.listen(3001, function() {
    console.log('app listening on port 3001 for project 2 !');
  })
```

**NOTE:** This requires that you switch to port `80` on server as that is the default port for request on any server.

If you'd want to get a more sophisticated solution wherein both these applications are sand-boxed into their own environment, you can go for [Virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/). Both of them offer same functionality but in different manner. They both can set up a isolated environment for your application so that you'r applications don't interact with each other.
To give you a perspective of this, 
let's say your application uses a enviornment-variable that you have set to 'Abra-kadabra' for project 1. Now if you refrence that enviornment variable in project 2, you'd still get 'Abra-kadabra' while you might want second project to have the value 'whoosh'
Virualbox or docker would set up a isolated system where in you can have this exact functionality available to you

Comment: what is the limit of express servers in a single server ?